# php fsockopen is NOT working

Tags: php, xml, seo, sitemap

I'm trying to ping a domain with a specific query information.

This should be extremely simple BUT it's not working.

So... Why so simple fsockopen php command is not working ?!

```
fsockopen('http://www.domain.com/test?q=https://example.com', 80);
```

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to http://www.domain.com/test?q=https://example.com:80 (Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in ...

Comment: Why are you using sockets for http? If you just need remote http capabilities (with tons of features for changing headers and stuff) try php cURL. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Yep! I have change it to cUrl. Working perfectly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fsockopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) accept only hostname.

- please use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) library
- or simple [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function

Comment: Yep ! file_get_contents super simple and working perfectly ! :) thanks !